# Check for value fetched from Union based on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries which i have done union of. The union gives me data as below:

```
ID    CATEGORY  CURRENT_NEW  ORDER  VOLUME  PRICE
-------------------------------------------------
1000  LIMIT     CURRENT       10    100       50
1000  TARGET    CURRENT       10    100       50
1000  LIMIT     NEW           10    100      100
1000  TARGET    NEW           10    100      100
```

Now I want to have a flag which will check if the PRICE for same ID, same category, same order and same Volume is equal or not.

While doing so, comparison must be done on the current_new column. For eg: Price of Current_New = New value with ID 1000 having category LIMIT, Order 10 and Volume 100 must be checked with Price of Current_New = Current value with ID 1000 having category LIMIT, Order 10 and Volume 100. If its equal then set the flag to 1 else 0.

Can someone please help me on this. I am stuck badly.

Comment: What would be your exact desired result from this query with your sample data?

Comment: My desired result will be to have one column in the last named CHECK_FLAG; basically i want to check whether the values based on my above comment/conditions is equal or not

Comment: My aim is to check that for one ID, one order, one volume and one category whether my PRICE for Current value is same or not from the New Value's Price; if it is not same then mark this flag as 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to write this query. You could for example use a left join to find exactly matching rows according to your criteria, if there is no match for a row with `NEW`, return 1, otherwise 0;

```
SELECT m.*, CASE WHEN comp.id IS NULL AND m.CURRENT_NEW='NEW'
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CHECK_FLAG
FROM mytable m
LEFT JOIN mytable comp
  ON m.CURRENT_NEW    = 'NEW'
 AND comp.CURRENT_NEW = 'CURRENT'
 AND m.CATEGORY       = comp.CATEGORY
 AND m.[ORDER]        = comp.[ORDER]
 AND m.VOLUME         = comp.VOLUME;
```

Note that this query assumes that there is only one CURRENT row matching each NEW row, otherwise it will give duplicates.

An alternate way to write it is using NOT EXISTS, which just checks the existence of a matching row and returns the value accordingly;

```
SELECT m.*, CASE WHEN CURRENT_NEW = 'NEW' AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM mytable comp 
  WHERE comp.CURRENT_NEW = 'CURRENT'
    AND m.CATEGORY = comp.CATEGORY
    AND m.[ORDER] = comp.[ORDER]
    AND m.VOLUME = comp.VOLUME
) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CHECK_FLAG
FROM mytable m;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test both](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5b0b0/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with window functions, if I understand the problem correctly:

```
select uq.*,
       (case when max(case when current_new = 'current' then price end) over
                         (partition by id, category, order, volume)) =
                  max(case when current_new = 'new' then price end) over
                         (partition by id, category, order, volume))
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag                  
from unionquery uq;
```